# Можно ли реализовать Push-уведомления в Android, не используя сервис Google?

Tags: android, уведомления, push-уведомления

Появилась задача реализовать Push-уведомления для приложения, но раньше я с ними не сталкивался. Нашёл кучу статей, но все они подразумевают использование **Google**-аккаунта. Можно ли обойтись без него?

Схема отправки сообщений следующая (поправьте если я не прав):

1. Устройство регистрируется в Google.
2. Сервер клиента отправляет уведомления в Google.
3. Google пересылает сообщение на устройство.

Что нужно серверу, что бы отправлять сообщения в **Google**? Сертификат может быть?

Как миновать сервис **Google**, что бы сервер отправлял уведомления прямо на устройство?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Без Google можно, но оно того не стоит. Если хотите потратить зря время, и лично разочароваться во всех альтернативных решениях, найти можно так: [*android push notification without google*](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20push%20notification%20without%20google&es_th=1). Меньше всего я разочаровался в [этом](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).
- Google-аккаунт нужен. Без него — невозможно (если делать через Google). Насколько я знаю, Google GCM не подразумевает покупку аккаунта разработчика. То есть, если не собираетесь публиковать в Play Store, то можно его и не покупать, Push-уведомления будут доступны всё равно, т.к. работают они через другой сервис.

А работает это так:

1. При первой установке приложения на устройство, Google выдаёт ему уникальный идентификатор для `Push Notifications`.
2. Вы этот идентификатор сохраняете у себя на сервере.
3. Когда нужно отправить `Push Notification` на устройство, вы говорите сервису Google, какие данные нужно отправить на какой идентификатор, и он отправляет.

Comment: Сейчас попробовал собрать такую схемку. На сайте гугла он сконфигурировал API key и Sender_ID. Я так понимаю эти данные нужны для сервера который будет слать уведомления? А токен это как бы регистрация конкретного устройства?

Comment: @FredGan, API key пооему в приложение надо вписать. Откройте любой гайд, там все написано.